# How to reauthorize domain at mailgun.com

Tags: dns, mailgun

I have domain that is already added by another developer at mailgun.com, 
but now i don't have access of that developer account at mailgun.com also smtp password has changed at mailgun.com account for my domain.

Now i have created new account at mailgun.com and wants to add my domain under this account, but i am getting error "This domain name is already taken".
I have complete access of my domain and hosting but don't have access of last mailgun.com.

however i already have removed TXT record for my domain associated with mailgun.com last account from my domains DNS setting.

my domain's DNS is hosted at godaddy.

Thanks!

Comment: write to support they may help you .